# NoClassDefFoundError: JavascriptInterface in API<JELLY_BEAN_MR1

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview, webchromeclient

As you know, since JELLY_BEAN it's needed to annotate with `@JavascriptInterface` all methods accessible via JavasScriptInterface.

I'm doing it while injecting some JavaScript and it's running ok in terminals with API>JELLY_BEAN_MR1. Nevertheless I have a NoClassDefFoundError in older devices.

This is my code:

```
wvPromo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(mDialog!=null && mDialog.isShowing()) mDialog.dismiss();
            view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "
                    + "var myEl = document.getElementById('mw-mf-main-menu-button');   "
                    + "myEl.addEventListener('click', function(){window.JSInterface.share();}, false);"
                    + "})();");
            view.addJavascriptInterface(this, "JSInterface");           
        }
    });.
...

@JavascriptInterface
public void share() {
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Share button");
    Intent i = Utils.shareContentIntent(this, "word", "Title");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

This is the Exception:

```
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.cleverox.flamencomovil/com.zonaapp.flamencomovil.PromotionActivity}: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662): Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:65)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getMembersInjector(InjectorImpl.java:950)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getMembersInjector(InjectorImpl.java:957)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.injectMembers(InjectorImpl.java:943)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at roboguice.inject.ContextScopedRoboInjector.injectMembersWithoutViews(ContextScopedRoboInjector.java:243)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.zonaapp.utils.roboguice.RoboSherlockActivity.onCreate(RoboSherlockActivity.java:60)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.zonaapp.flamencomovil.PromotionActivity.onCreate(PromotionActivity.java:40)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    ... 11 more
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Native Method)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:262)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java:188)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotation(AccessibleObject.java:196)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getAtInject(InjectionPoint.java:466)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:664)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:356)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:90)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.access$000(MembersInjectorStore.java:34)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:42)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:39)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    ... 23 more
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.webkit.JavascriptInterface in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.cleverox.flamencomovil-1.apk]
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-30 12:42:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(13662):    ... 36 more
```

Comment: Given the nature of your stack trace, this would appear to be a RoboGuice issue.

Comment: Right! It's a RoboGuice problem. I've change from'roboActivity' to 'Activity' and now it works but... I can't suspect what's wrong with RoboGuice.

Comment: This is RoboGuice issue - https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/issues/328
I am also getting the same error, help in this area would be appreciable